# VS 2017 args to Main function is not what set under Properties for Debug

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, command-line-interface

When debugging my application in Visual Studio 2017 i get a wierd problem with the args in the Main method.

Under Properties->Debug->Application arguments i have this:

`import --environment=At --id="3E706F28-2B08-4B39-85BA-94B1893C0168" -p`

But the args variable in Main contains these items:

```
[0] = "import"
[1] = "--id=b339afa3-7d9c-413b-954a-f4e0bc3d89ea"
[2] = "-p"
[3] = "-e"
[4] = "Test"
[5] = "import"
[6] = "--environment=At"
[7] = "--"
```

Notice for example that the guid is not the same. It seems that my arguments starts at index 5 with some others at 0 to 4.

I do recognice the arguments before as some old ones i used earlier before upgrading to VS2017. Is there some cache that i need to clean or something.

I have tried searching for the wrong guid under the solution folder but did not get any match.

Any one who knows how to get rid of the old arguments?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't debugging the wrong configuratino?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: I have no configurations to choose from. At the top it says Configuration: N/A and the dropdown is grayed out.

Comment: You have Debug and Release at least. Visual Studio doesn't have any such bug, people would have noticed by now. I've also upgraded from VS 2012 to 2015 and then to 2017, kept up with all updates. The only time when the wrong arguments were used was when I tried debugging `Release` instead of `Debug`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Ah, you meen that configuration. I have been using Debug. But you might be onto somethig. I changed to Release and then i only got the correct arguments.

Comment: I found the problem after looking up where the configurations is stored. It was in the <projectfile>.csproject.user file. But the arguments i enter from within VS is stored in a file called launchSettings.json. Apparently VS merges the arguments from both these sources. Seems like strange behaviour to me but now it works anyways after clearing the old .user-file. Many thanks @panagiotis-kanavos for taking the time to help!

Comment: Which means you are using .NET Core, which uses a new build system and stores those values in `launshsettings.json`. `launchSettings.json` is used to store profile settings, as explained in [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [Working with Environments and Launch Settings in ASP.NET Core](https://exceptionnotfound.net/working-with-environments-and-launch-settings-in-asp-net-core/).

Comment: BTW `launchSetting.json` isn't just for Visual Studio. It's used by `dotnet run` if it exists. This can lead to confusion when developing with different profiles that don't behave the same when published/deployed.